# Advice on RTOS for AVR?

Tags: avr, avr-gcc, rtos

I need a very tiny RTOS for AVR similar to mRTOS which just has two files (mrtos.h and mrtos.c).

Can anyone please provide any advice?

Comment: What is mRTOS? Aside from a definition ("Modular Real Time Operating System"), I can't find anything about it online.

Comment: http://kazus.ru/forums/showthread.php?t=10841

Comment: "just two files" tells us nothing about the sizeof mRTOS since file size is virtually unlimited.  Anything could be implemented in a single (arbitrarily large) file.  Also a link to that would be helpful mRTOS is too generic to find what you might be referring to; the link above is not very helpful, its a link to page in Cyrillic that contains somewhere a link to a page that claims to have an article about mRTOS, but the page is broken (at least on my Chromebook).  The link should also be in your question, not added in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out FreeRTOS for AVR or search for some board specific ones on github.

Comment: FreeRTOS  - too cumbersome.
I need a cooperative RTOS

Comment: I found the answer to github. Thank U.

Comment: @Fulrus : So you marked this as the accepted answer, but it is not an answer that is acceptable to you!?   Perhaps you could post the answer you "found" for the benefit of the SO community?  Or have you simply changed your mind about FreeRTOS? (in which case delete the comment).

Answer (score 0):

For something really small, take a look at the Arduino scheduler:

http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Scheduler

Pretty simple to adapt to almost anything with a c/c++ compiler. Note, this only gives you pretty basic cooperative multitasking. If you need OS services like semaphores, mutexes, mailboxes, etc. . . you'd need to look for something less lightweight.